# Xen error on CentOS

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen

During the creating of a new virtual server in xen using this command

```
xen-create-image --hostname=minecraft.koanhosting.com --ip 87.98.249.146 --install -method=debootstrap
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Writing inode tables:  0/32^H^H^H^H^H 1/32^H^H^H^H^H 2/32^H^H^H^H^H 3/32^H^H^H^H^H 4/32^H^H^H^H^H 5/32^H^H^H^H^H 6/32^H^H^H^H^H 7/32^H^H^H^H^H 8/32^H^H^H^H^H 9/32^H^H^H^H^H10/32^H^$
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 28 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
Done
Installation method: debootstrap

Copying files from host to image.
Copying files from /var/cache/apt/archives -> /tmp/LYC7oAQoxq/var/cache/apt/archives
Done
Done
I: Retrieving Release
E: Failed getting release file http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/etch/Release

Copying files from new installation to host.
Copying files from /tmp/LYC7oAQoxq/var/cache/apt/archives -> /var/cache/apt/archives
Done
Done
The installation of the new system has failed.

The system is missing the common file: /bin/ls
Done
System installation failed.  Aborting
```

Can't seem to find any resources on google at all for this error. I have a feeling it's to do with debootstrap, not sure though.

Comment: I don't know about `xen-create-image`, but your issue is caused by [Debian "Etch" being unsupported as of 2010-02-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_history) (and thus disappeared from the mirror)

Comment: @sr_ IMO, that should be an answer.

Comment: @jordanm, you might be right; I expanded it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the default settings for `xen-create-image` try to `debootstrap` **Etch**, a Debian release [*unsupported for almost <del>two</del> three years*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_history).

The Debian Wiki has an entry on Xen, with a [section about creating a Debian guest image using `xen-tools`](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen#Using_xen-tools).  It gives an example call to `xen-create-image` like this:

```
xen-create-image [..] --dist <lenny|squeeze|maverick|whatever>
```

thus you could try adding `--dist squeeze` (stable) or `--dist wheezy` (testing) to your command line.

If this doesn't already do the trick, have a closer look at `/etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf` and `man xen-create-image`.

Comment: I actually wanted to install CentOS, not Debian. I didn't realise that debootstrap was only for debian. Using Rinse now and everything seems to be fine now :) Thanks anyway

Comment: @jordanm: Oh... right. Thanks for the edit `:)`